# Does Homebrew keep a log of installed packages/casks?

Tags: homebrew

Anyone know if Homebrew keeps a log of previously-installed packages?
I know I can do a `brew list`, but that shows all packages *and* their dependencies ... I was hoping instead to just see the explicitly-requested packages (i.e. not with the implicitly-installed dependencies).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Homebrew doesn’t have a global log, but it does keep that information at the formula level:

```
$ brew info --json=v1 git | jq '.[0].installed[0]|{installed_on_request,installed_as_dependency}'    
{
  "installed_on_request": true,
  "installed_as_dependency": false
}
```

With a bit of [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) you can get the full list of formulae installed on request. It’s slow because it needs to load every single formula’s JSON payload, but it works:

```
brew info --json=v1 --installed | jq -r '.[]|select(.installed[0].installed_on_request).full_name'
```

Comment: There is now `brew leaves --installed-on-request`

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`brew leaves`](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage)

Comment: This is incomplete. You may have installed some package (formula) that eventually became a dependency of another formula. That package would thus not appear in `brew leaves`’ output.